# Cannot write a specific string into a mssql database

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am very new to databases and python. I read many logfiles with my script and write the data into a MSSql Express Database and use pymssql. The logfiles are in .csv format and looks like this:

> ID;REQUEST
>   3gix2v2h2mjmmybrf4p5blbm;49db032f0a144efeb1e0e690b4e6a26f;  kzbcaakb2ex44dnhrqi4kgvt;28042afb61b44c539fbaa1ac4c303665;

The ID and REQUEST are defined as VARCHAR(50) in the database.

My script works fine and i write about 70000 entries in the db, till in one of the logfiles the line with the values:

> 0xaf3azaza5sb1ztogqfdmwb;934d4978a40c451b8f4080791f752453

appears. I get the Error:

> pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near 'zaza5sb1ztogqfdmwb'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15)

This is my script:

```
for filename in os.listdir(sFolderlocation):
    if "archive" in  filename:            
        with open(sFolderlocation + os.sep + filename, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
            skipfirstline = True
            for row in reader:
                werte=[]
                if skipfirstline:
                    skipfirstline = False
                    continue
                werte.append(row[0])    #ID
                werte.append(row[1])    #maprequest
                werte=tuple(werte)                    
                cursor.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO webgis_test (SESSIONID,MAPREQUESTID) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                    werte)
                conn.commit()
```

is the "0xaf3a" somehow interpreted as hex and so i get the error? Can you help me fix this? Thank you for your help

When someone else sees something in the code what i can make better, i really would like to hear your tips :)

Comment: well it seems to be failing right at a `;`.  I'm not familiar with python, so I can't really say - but are you correctly parameterizing your params?

Comment: The error indicates the value is being passed is a literal not enclosed in quotes.  The leading '0x' results in a hex literal.  I can't speak to the best remedy since I'm not a Python guy.  A prepared query will certainly avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dan Guzman. The literal was not encloesd in quotes.

This python code works:

```
cursor.execute(
"INSERT INTO webgis_test2 (SESSIONID, MAPREQUESTID) VALUES ('"+werte[0]+"','"+werte[1]+"');")
```

Comment: Just want to add that the only literals that need to be enclosed in quotes are string, date/time, and xml.  Integer and numeric literals should not be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL VARCHAR fields are used to store non-unicode data. It looks like there is an invalid character in the CSV file that MSSQL cannot store in a VARCHAR field.

Note that the line that you posted starts with `0xaf3a` which is probably a hex code of this invalid character.

If your file has these 6 symbols `0xaf3a` and not one unicode character in the bogus line then I guess it is a bug in pymssql. Try updating to the latest version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes there are 6 Symbols in my file and no invalid characters. i am using the newest version of pymssql, i also think its a bug of pymssql. thank you

Comment: no there is no bug i oversaw the comment of Dan Guzman. The SQL statement of my code was faulty